# wp_login_url not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display login link for the user with redirection to home page

```
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()) : ?>
        <a href="<?php wp_login_url(get_option('siteurl')); ?> "> login</a>
```

However this produces the following

```
<a href=" "> login</a>
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to echo it

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url(get_option('siteurl')); ?> "> login</a>
```