# Wordpress login link does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use this as a login link in my wp site:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_login_url() ); ?>">Log in</a>
```

It prints the correct link which is www.mysite.com/wp-login.php. But when click that link, it redirects to the current page and does not go the login page. Somehow it actually performing a logout. It is returning to the current page with an url like this:

```
www.mysite.com/mypage/logout=success
```

I tried clearing the cache, cookies, etc and also regenerated the htaccess file. But it does not working out for me. This is may be very stupid, but am I missing something here? Is there any security reason for that wp is acting like this? When I copy the link and paste it in a new tab, it just works! Can anyone lighten me up about what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are logged in, you cannot view the login page, what happens when you click it when your logged out?

Comment: I know that. I put a logic so that the link is only visible if you are not logged in. If I am logged in, it shows a log out link instead and that logout link works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wp\_login\_url not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153836/wp-login-url-not-working)